# Trenching requirements for utilities in a outdoors kitchen

Tags: electrical, water, gas, utilities, trench

I would like to build a small outdoors kitchen, with gas (for the grill), electricity, water and drain - sewage (for a sink).

I spoke this morning with a person in the building department of my city and he said I do not need any permit for a structure lower than 4ft and not enclosed on more than three sides.

For this, I was left on my own on the area I need more guidance, that is the trenching requirements and best practices. I will try to get more info from the city but is there a list of known good ways to run the above utilities? What are the most modern ways to deliver the above utilities?

PEX for water instead of copper; also low-pressure gas can run in designated flexible conduits; should I run electricity in a conduit (flexible or rigid?)

Comment: Electric definitely in conduit..... PVC

Comment: Using PVC conduit for electrical provides much more future flexibility. If you live in an area governed by the NEC the Electrical depth requirements for direct burial cables and conduits can be found in table 300.5 https://duckduckgo.com/?q=nec+table+300.5&atb=v156-3b_&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: Very good, at least two feet deep. Any reason I should prefer rigid sections to be glued together vs a single run of flexible conduit?

Comment: Rigid PVC is easier to pull cable through.... and to remove if you ever need to upgrade. It's also a whole lot cheaper.

Comment: Is there going to be decking over this area connecting to the house? I agree with pvc conduit but if the area from the house to the kitchen equipment is covered by a deck it can be on the surface, but you will want your water lines buried if you have freezing conditions.

Comment: About rigid PCV being cheaper - yes, but the cost of the material is minimal compared to labor and the time it takes to glue it together etc might offset that. However, it seems both solutions are otherwise equivalent.

No decking or anything, the area might *in principle* have some vehicular traffic but I don't plan to do that very often at all. No frost line here.